# Strange liquid sloshing noise from gearbox / transmission

Tags: noise, manual-transmission, subaru, wrx

My Subaru WRX has been making a strange noise for the last 5000 miles or so (it may have done it before that, but that's the first I remember):

When I pull away in first, or sometimes if I just rev the engine when stationary, there is a distinct noise of flowing liquid, like slush pouring from a bucket, coming from just about where the gear stick is.

My assumption is that it is oil lubricating the gearbox, however I have never heard it in any other car so it seems weird to me. My next service isn't for a couple of months but if this is not good I'll book it in sooner.

I don't notice any problems - changing gear is as slick as ever, there are no clunky shifts.

After paying a lot more attention to the noise, which is a challenge as it is intermittent, it does happen when revving and pulling away, as well as revving with car in gear and the clutch in **or** in neutral with the clutch out.

Comment: I know you know your stuff, but are you *positive* the sound isn't from the HVAC housing?  I only say that because I've been badly bitten by heater core/evaporator/pluggeddrainsandmycarpetiswet voodoo thingie noises in the past.

Comment: Yeah - loads of diagnosis attempts. The AC noise is where it should be, and is very AC-like :-)

Comment: I assume you checked the gear fluid level? Is the stick moving when accelerating?

Comment: Have you tried revving the engine with/without the clutch pedal depressed? Same noise? If so, I'd suggest the noise isn't originating in the gearbox. Not being there to hear the noise, I'd suggest it could be from the heater core and would check to ensure the coolant levels are completely up to snuff.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2  Yes, that was my first guess but not being able to hear it....   What does the noise smell like??

Comment: @SteveRacer - Smell like? ;-)

Comment: @SteveRacer - see my update. I beginning to think you are right

Comment: @RoryAlsop  I'm telling you, I've been badly stung by this in the past.  You might also play with the temperature control at both extreme positions to see if that makes a difference.  *Sloshing* (when coming to a stop) is indicative of plugged housing drain(s).  A squirty *Fwooshhhh* noise relative to water pump RPM says heater core/coolant issue to me.  *The "squirty Fwooshhh" noise description is proprietary and not to be used without my permission...*

Comment: Also, a bad TXV or low refrigerant can also cause the same noise in the evaporator, but the AC clutch would have to be on (engaged), the noise is much more subtle, and the AC wouldn't work well.  *That one is "whisper Pswiiishh" ...*

Comment: "Squirty fwooshhh" sounds about right. Would you like to post it as an answer along with any guidance as to whether I would need to do anything about it, or just wait until next regular service (UK is not really a country that needs AC)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took the car in for service, and @SteveRacer was right. It was the air con - they did a full flush and recharge (it was the 120,000 mile service so it was about time anyway) and the problem has completely gone.

I would have sworn from where it sounded like the noise was coming from that it had to be gearbox. And I was embarrassingly wrong :-)